# how to build a null distribution

Tags: r, statistics, sas, spss

> 1:I would like to create a synthetic dataset of 14.000 genes (rows) and 250 samples (columns of the matrix).
>   How this can be done?
>   2: after this, I would like to infer gene regulation using for ex algorithms of mutual information. I know how and in fact I have a network.
>   3: I would like to know if the net I had is due by chance or not. To do this, one common approach is to schuffle samples or genes, 1000 times, to create 1000 net and plot a null distribution to validate the net you previously (point 2) obtained. This is called bootstrap. 
>   Is there another method?

Best,

E.

Comment: This question is better suited for [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/), as it is a purely statistical question. Neither you or I have enough reputation to migrate it though.

Comment: Thank you a lot! this is a good suggestion by itself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sample` function in R is the basic way to construct random permutations of existing data. It's not clear what you want, and an additional thought was that you might just need to be pointed to the `runif` function for generating random Uniform sequences. If you had 1000 objects of a particular sort in an object vector, obj:

```
 sample( obj )   # returns a permuted sequence
 # Same as ...
 obj[ sample(length(obj)) ]
```

Whether that is a "null distribution" is up to you to decide. (And that request for "all" of the methods to do any particular task in R will be viewed as being excessively demanding. There are often a large number of methods, and even asking for the "best" will increase you chances of getting your question closed.)

Comment: Hi DWin, thank you! The problem is that there's just a confusion in my mind about methods for cross validation. For ex. there's the bootstrap, the leave-one-out ecc. ecc. I need a sort of "list" with a minimal description, to better understand which method to use according to my situation. Anyway thank you to suggest me the "sample" function.

Comment: Sadly, there are books written on this topic, and you are providing precious little to guide the discussion.

Comment: I totally agree with you..this is a new field for me and I need just to bearing in this see!

Comment: Your Q is still not closed. You still have some time to make this sufficiently specific , but time is running out.